# How to 'touch' all files which include a particular header file?

Tags: c++

So I have this big C++ project, and I have made changes to one header file. Therefore, I would need to recompile all source files that 'include' that header. Other than doing a text search on the entire project, is there any other way to 'touch' all files that include that header file? I am using Microsoft Visual C++ compiler.

**Update:** I am not using Visual Studio. We use makefiles for compiling (for historical reasons).

Comment: Uh... that's handled by VS, why do you want to do that manually?

Comment: If you need it so much, maybe it's better to think to forward declarations, in order to avoid compiling all the time.

Comment: the sense of a Makefile is that all dependencies will be solved. In your case make knows which files are depended from others if the rules are given to the Makefile. This can also be done in a automated fashion by declaring this as a rule. Manual touching files is definitive the wrong solution.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is built-in into Visual Studio. As far as

- timestamps are valid
- you're not switching to different system timezones/tinkering with the date/time options

VS should always, when prompted for building (**not** rebuilding), rebuild the sources that include a modified header.

For more information [take a look at the documentation pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483.aspx)